# How to create a healthy VPC-Native GKE cluster with Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc

Through Terraform, I am trying to create a VPC-Native GKE cluster in a single zone (europe-north1-b), with a separate node-pool, with the GKE cluster and node-pool in their own VPC Network.

My code looks like the following:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "gke_cluster" {
  description              = "GKE Cluster for personal projects"
  initial_node_count       = 1
  location                 = "europe-north1-b"
  name                     = "prod"
  network                  = google_compute_network.gke.self_link
  remove_default_node_pool = true
  subnetwork               = google_compute_subnetwork.gke.self_link

  ip_allocation_policy {
    cluster_secondary_range_name  = local.cluster_secondary_range_name
    services_secondary_range_name = local.services_secondary_range_name
  }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "gke" {
  auto_create_subnetworks         = false
  delete_default_routes_on_create = false
  description                     = "Compute Network for GKE nodes"
  name                            = "${terraform.workspace}-gke"
  routing_mode                    = "GLOBAL"
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "gke" {
  name          = "prod-gke-subnetwork"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.255.0.0/16"
  region        = "europe-north1"
  network       = google_compute_network.gke.id

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = local.cluster_secondary_range_name
    ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/10"
  }

  secondary_ip_range {
    range_name    = local.services_secondary_range_name
    ip_cidr_range = "10.64.0.0/10"
  }
}

locals {
  cluster_secondary_range_name  = "cluster-secondary-range"
  services_secondary_range_name = "services-secondary-range"
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "gke_node_pool" {
  cluster    = google_container_cluster.gke_cluster.name
  location   = "europe-north1-b"
  name       = terraform.workspace
  node_count = 1
  
  node_locations = [
    "europe-north1-b"
  ]

  node_config {
    disk_size_gb    = 100
    disk_type       = "pd-standard"
    image_type      = "cos_containerd"
    local_ssd_count = 0
    machine_type    = "g1-small"
    preemptible     = false
    service_account = google_service_account.gke_node_pool.email
  }
}

resource "google_service_account" "gke_node_pool" {
  account_id   = "${terraform.workspace}-node-pool"
  description  = "The default service account for pods to use in ${terraform.workspace}"
  display_name = "GKE Node Pool ${terraform.workspace} Service Account"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "gke_node_pool" {
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.gke_node_pool.email}"
  role   = "roles/viewer"
}
```

However, whenever I apply this Terraform code, I receive the following error:

```
google_container_cluster.gke_cluster: Still creating... [24m30s elapsed]
google_container_cluster.gke_cluster: Still creating... [24m40s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Error waiting for creating GKE cluster: All cluster resources were brought up, but: component "kube-apiserver" from endpoint "gke-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-yyyy" is unhealthy.
│ 
│   with google_container_cluster.gke_cluster,
│   on gke.tf line 1, in resource "google_container_cluster" "gke_cluster":
│    1: resource "google_container_cluster" "gke_cluster" {
│ 
╵
```

My cluster is then auto-deleted.

I can find no problem with my Terraform code/syntax, and have searched through Google Cloud Logging to find a more detailed error message with no luck.

So, how do I create a HEALTHY VPC-Native GKE cluster with Terraform?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the issue seemed to be with having the large subnetwork secondary ranges.

As shown in the question, I had ranges:

- `10.0.0.0/10` for the `cluster_secondary_range`.
- `10.64.0.0/10` for the `services_secondary_range`.

These `/10` CIDRs cover `4194304` IP addresses each, which I figured might be too large for Google/GKE to handle(?) - especially since all of the GKE documentation uses CIDRs covering much smaller ranges for the cluster & services.

I decided to shrink these CIDR ranges to see if would help:

- `10.0.0.0/12` for the `cluster_secondary_range`.
- `10.16.0.0/12` for the `services_secondary_range`.

These `/12` CIDRs cover `1048576` IP addresses each.
My cluster was created successfully after this change:

```
google_container_cluster.gke_cluster: Creation complete after 5m40s
```

Not sure WHY Google / GKE can't handle larger CIDR ranges for the cluster & services, but `/12` is good enough for me and allows for successful creation of the cluster.